# Using Paypal API for payment transactions

Tags: java, paypal

I am planning to use Paypal for payment transactions in our application. Here I need to create the Merchant account(Business Pro) and the customers for that merchant have to be added. Once the accounts creation is successful, from client account to merchant account. I have referred "https://developer.paypal.com/", could not find the exact API method to be called. Can I get any sample code snippets for these API calls to be done in Java? Please suggest if any one have the idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  You just want to know which APIs you should be using to integrate PayPal Payments Pro?

Comment: I want to know which webservice method call of Paypal API should I use for creating the Business Pro account. Got to know from the documentation, that we need to use "adaptiveAccountsService.createAccount" call to add customer accounts corresponding to that merchant once Business Pro account is created. Please correct me if Iam wrong.

Comment: To my knowledge the API won't let you activate Pro.  You can create the business account using the CreateAccount API, but then to add Pro the user would have to apply for that directly.